# Implied types from a generic class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

In the following code:

```
interface IMyInterface<X>
{
    X Get();
}

class MyInterface : IMyInterface<int>
{
    int Get();
}

class MyClass<T, U> where T : IMyInterface<U>
{
    U Value;
}
```

U is always going to be a function of T.  However, to use MyClass, I have to do this:

```
MyClass<MyInterface, int> instance;
```

It would be nice if I could just type:

```
MyClass<MyInterface> instance;
```

And have U be implied to be an int.  Is there anyway to restructure my code so I don't need to specify U like that?